# How to find a machine that is listening to a particular port on a LAN using nmap?

Tags: nmap

I just installed nmap (never used it before). I want to see which machine on the network is listening to port 1234. How can I do that using the GUI of nmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
nmap -p 1234 -A -v 10.10.*.*
```

Answer (score 1):

`nmap -v -A -p 1234 192.168.1.1-255`  This command will scan your entire subnet

Comment: what if the machine has an ip like 10.10.10.10?

Comment: This is a way-overpowered command. The `-A` switch turns on service version detection, traceroute, OS fingerprinting, and NSE script scan. The OS fingerprinting will fail because you're only scanning one port; the traceroute is probably unnecessary because it's a LAN.

Answer (score 0):

The officially supported (and included!) GUI for [Nmap](http://nmap.org/) is [Zenmap](http://nmap.org/zenmap/). It uses Profiles to choose common options, but the command line is clearly editable, as well. To get started, choose the Regular Scan profile, which removes the extra timing and scan mode arguments. Then, enter your target in the Target box. To scan a local network, you can use CIDR notation (e.g. `10.10.0.0/16`) or octet ranges (e.g. 10.10.0-255.0-255).

To scan just one port, use the `-p` option with the port number. It is usually helpful to specify verbose output, too, with `-v`. Altogether, your command line will look something like this:

```
nmap -p 1234 -v 10.10.10.0/24
```

Then click the Scan button to begin scanning.